# Python выводит странные символы

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

есть такой код:

```
from time import sleep
word = ""
words = []
data = open('dict.txt', 'r')
d = str(data.read())
print(d)
for sym in d:
    # print(sym)
    if sym == ',':
        print(word)
        words.append(word)
        word = ""
    elif sym == ".":
        print(word)
        words.append(word)
        break
    else:
        word = word + sym
for w in words:
    print(w)
    sleep(0.7*len(w))
```

И .txt документ с определёнными русскими словами, написанными через запятую и пробел. Когда запускаю скрипт вместо русских символов выдается вот это:

```
РїСЂРёРІРµС‚, РїРѕРєР°.

РїСЂРёРІРµС‚
 РїРѕРєР°
РїСЂРёРІРµС‚
 РїРѕРєР°
```

Что мне сделать, чтобы выводились слова на русском, вместо этого неизвестно чего?

Comment: на первый взгляд дело в кодировке, попробуйте установить encoding на utf - 8 или на ASCII

Comment: и приложите содержимое текстовика

Comment: В текстовом файле у вас текст в кодировке utf-8. Чтобы скрипт прочитал текст в этой кодировке, нужно ее указать при открытии файла: `data = open('dict.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: да, он читал это в другой кодировке

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрим на схему из статьи "[Как распознать кракозябры?](https://habr.com/ru/post/147843/)":

[image: схема]

Видим что это UTF-8, декодированная как Win-1251.

Указываем верную кодировку при открытие файла

```
data = open('dict.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Вуаля.